# How can get the current location of the device using Geolocation in react native app

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am new to the react-native and i want to get the device current location. How can i do so by using Geolocation. I have gone through the react-native documentation.But still i cannot get the location.

This is my code

i have add the following line in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and this my code so far to console the current location

```
        const location = Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        console.log("location", location)
```

(I am building my app in android)

Answer (score 0):

`Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so the [location info is returned in callback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#getcurrentposition):

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(location => console.log('location', location));
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Configuration and Permissions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#configuration-and-permissions) section and then you can use:

```
navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization()
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(location => console.log('location', location));
```

> As a browser polyfill, this API is available through the navigator.geolocation global - you do not need to import it.